# Can i fixed UINavigationBar's TopBar on the way swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want UINavigationBar's Topbar on the way swipe gesture.

My storyboard is like this:

```
LoginViewController(UINavigationController) =>(pushViewController) RegisterViewController
```

I tried some methods, The most similar answer is

1. LoginViewController's Navigation bar set to hidden. `setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)`
2. RegisterViewController's Navigation bar set to show. `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`

But, This method is **must have LoginViewController's navigation bar set to hidden.**

Is there another good way?

Result) https://puu.sh/Ei30r/14dc30d883.jpg

I want) https://puu.sh/Ei32K/437b731c80.jpg

Replace img tag with link because i have not at least 10 reputation.

Sorry,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this and it worked. You can give it a try.

on LoginViewController's

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

on RegisterViewController's

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Can not keep navigation bar showing of LoginViewController?

Comment: @YUKIYUKI you mentioned you want it like this (https://puu.sh/Ei32K/437b731c80.jpg) so I assume LoginVC has no NavigationBar

Comment: Oh thanks.. Additionally.. I want know code that LoginVC has navigation bar case.

Comment: @YUKIYUKI Ok, let me assume again. I assume your login has navigationBar.

So you can add the following code `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)` in the `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`

Comment: Thank you for much! I appreciate to you.